# Django: Many-to-many with through vs 2x one-to-many

Tags: sql, django, orm, many-to-many, relational-database

Reading, the Django docs on many-to-many relationships when you need an extra field on the intermediary table, it's not clear to me what you gain by defining the relationship as many-to-many vs just having a foreign key to the intermediary model in each of your models.

For instance, in the example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Why bother with the ManyToManyField line? Does it allow you to refer to the relationship any differently? Does it change something in the admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with the `ManyToManyField line`: M2M fields are django `fields` which are useful for many model field interfaces like `ModelAdmin` or `ModelForm` (declaring fields, excluding, default widgets). It also generate helper methods like easy to access m2m managers and auto m2m saving in the admin.

Here's a quick example for what the field does automatically for the admin panel: you can't save a through model without the main object saved first. The admin handles this behavior with a `save_m2m` after the main object is saved automatically. If you did not use an m2m field, you'd have to code this kind of logic yourself.

I think you'd use this field when your project works with m2m fields but you just need a small amount of additional information. That way your code is virtually the same as a typical m2m relationship but when you need it, you can query the extra info.

Otherwise, adding a mere "date_added" field would require writing admin widgets, save_model hooks, ModelForm representation, etc.

You're right though that removing the m2m line with a through model won't make any database changes and you could ultimately replace the m2mfield functionality with the default ForeignKey reverse managers without much harm.

```
model.m2m_through_set.all() # this would work
model.m2m_through_set.create(target=target_instance)
```